# Why can't I filter on one new field in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework, endpoint

So I'm editing an existing codebase using Django Rest Framework, and I added a new field to a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    the_new_field = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
```

I've got a serializer, which is fairly basic:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
        )
```

So to the serializer I simply added the new field:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'the_new_field',
        )
```

I can call the endpoint using `name` using `?name=awesomename`, which actually filters based on `awesomename`, but when I call the endpoint using `?the_new_field=123456` it simply returns all the records in the database.

What am I missing here? How can I make it filter based on this new field?

Comment: I've pointed out below a sollution using `django-filter`, but I'm missing your view on this question, can you provide us with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like [`django-filter`](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter). It will handle filtering for you, and it's simple to write as a `serializer`.

Here is how you can [integrate with DRF](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html). DRF also recommends using it [in their docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend). Or follow along:

Install `django-filter` with pip.

```
pip install django-filter
```

Then add `django_filters` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
]
```

If you want to use the `django-filter` backend by default, add it to the `DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS` setting.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
        ...
    ),
}
```

Or add the filter backend to an individual `View` or `ViewSet`.

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class YourView(generics.ListAPIView):
    ...
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
```

Then add the filter to your current view as follows:

```
class MyModelList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['name', 'the_new_field']
```

Comment: I don't often favor answers pointing at 3rd party libraries- but this is probably good advice. At this point I'm not even sure why drf ships without `django-filter`.

Comment: @rob I'm adding an example, just trying to make it work locally, but pointing out first to speed up the process. I do also favor more examples than links, it's also the SO guideline.